# Computer feels laggy running Linux but okay with Windows 10 don't know why?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, cpu, lag

- **Processor**: AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics      3.90 GHz
- **Installed RAM**: 8.00 GB (7.20 GB usable)
- **System type**: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
- **Pen and touch**: No pen or touch input is available for this display
- **HARD DISK DRIVE**: ***TOSHIBA***(every os uses the same hard disk with the same amount of partition)

This is my computers specification. Now my question is when run Windows 10 on my computer it is literally faster(*performance, dragging an application, startup of an application etc.*) than running Linux (arch base{KDE PLASMA}, Debian base tried{KDE PLASMA}).

I don't know why does it happen but it really troubles me cause I know linux should run faster on my PC as it consumes less RAM and moreover the desktop is blurry too in Linux rather than Windows.

Comment: Are you testing with the OSes installed in the same drive or equivalent? If not, e.g. Windows on a SSD and Linux on an HDD (like many people do and then rant about it), then you can't compare.

Comment: @John AMD Graphics drivers are open-source and already included/supported at the kernel level. No user installable drivers are needed. "Drivers" is unlikely to be the problem here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have the same hdd for both OSes

Comment: Arch feels more laggier and slower than debian but debian feels also slow compared to windows 10.

Comment: Oh, is it a HDD after all? That's the problem then. By "literally faster" you probably mean boot, not actual performance after initial boot. Well, it happens that Windows has Fast Startup by default which is a trick, hybrid hibernation. For many reasons you should disable it, especially when dual-booting. Now compare again. No current OS should be installed in HDD.

Comment: No @ChanganAuto the application startup performance dragging everything slows down.

Comment: I am using KDE PLASMA desktop environment @ChanganAuto

Comment: @ChanganAuto the things you told I did that before installing my Linux os

Comment: I think there is no solution or anything for it then there is nothing to do.